# Is it correct to use the phrase "drive distance"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Is it correct to use the phrase "drive distance" for expressing the amount of distance I drove or intend to drive. Or should it be "driving distance"?

I tried thinking of other examples: "sleep habits" and "sleeping habits" both sound ok, but "eat habits" sounds wrong...

Comment: English is odd like that. Use *driving* distance. But if you want to talk about the distance you can cover, be aware that *driving range* starts to sound like golf.

Comment: You beat me by seconds,@Lawrence

Comment: English is strange. *Drive time* is idiomatic, but *drive distance* is much less so. The expression does occur in native speech, it's just much less common that *driving time*. It's common to speak of the morning commute as "my morning drive". In that case, you have a specific thing that is named, and *drive distance* sounds much better. *Distance* has now become an attribute of a particular drive.

Comment: ... journey length. But apparently, _driving distance_ is the preferred choice {[Google 2grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1940&year_end=2019&content=drive+distance%2Cdriving+distance&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrive%20distance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdriving%20distance%3B%2Cc0)}.

Comment: @PhilSweet Yes, it's quite common to see properties, particularly holiday lets, being described as being "within easy driving distance of the local amenities" although "a short drive from the local amenities" is even more common.